# setting timer in cocos2d-x js

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

```
i=0;
    while (i<10)
        {
        var objectLabel = cc.Sprite("res/rect.png", cc.rect(0, 0, 100, 100));
        function getRandomInt(min, max) 
            {
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
            }
        objectLabel.x = getRandomInt(50, size.width);
        objectLabel.y = size.height-40;
        setTimeout(this.addChild(objectLabel, 5), 500);
        objectLabel.runAction(cc.spawn(cc.moveBy(0.8, cc.p(0, size.height*(-1)+210))));
        i++;
        }
```

How can I set the timer of delay in performing WHILE each 0.6 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

Change these two lines in your code

1- Yor should use 'new' to create new Sprite

2- Inside setTimeout a function should be there which should be bind with 'this' to use functions of current class otherwise it will throw error can not find blah blah.

```
        var objectLabel = new cc.Sprite("res/rect.png", cc.rect(0, 0, 100, 100));



        setTimeout(function(){this.addChild(objectLabel, 5)}.bind(this), 600);
```

Answer (score -1):

The second parameter to setTimeout() should be your delay, where delay is in microseconds, (600 microseconds = 0.6 second).

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work at all. in process it works the same way if I wrote just this.addChild(objectLabel, 5) :(